# How to log user events?

Tags: aframe

I'm very new to programming and I'm using WebVR on glitch.com. With my program, I will have users choose options on the screen. I'm wondering how I can log all of the user's options automatically? As in, once the user has finished, I can look into a folder or somewhere and see the options that the user chose. I hope this makes sense. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This isn't a JavaScript question, even though aframe is a JavaScript framework. Though your question may be narrowly scoped in an aframe context (I don't know, I haven't dealt with aframe), from a JavaScript context it is overly broad and likely to be closed as such. I would recommend [edit]ing your question to remove the [tag:javascript] tag.

Comment: You want something like: https://heatmap.me/ or if you want something simpler, google for "logging in javascript"

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you don't need to save the options permanently, save them in a JavaScript variable.

If you need to save them permanently, save them using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Files and folders are problematic to access from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

if using `localStorage` is an option, there is an official [motion capture component](https://github.com/dmarcos/aframe-motion-capture-components). You can record
 the HMD, and the controllers, and then replay all the user's activities.

It's quite simple, You just add

```
<a-scene avatar-recorder>
</a-scene>
```

You can use a couple properties:

```
avatar-recorder="autoRecord: true; recordingName: rec.json"
```

to make the component record the player when the page loads.

---

Then You can spectate and watch the user with another scene:

```
<a-scene avatar-replayer="src: rec.json">
</a-scene>
```

I think I've seen a a-frame's Kevin Ngo posting about testing VR websites this way.